# Render a dictionary with object list as values in django but template not showing values

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, dictionary, view

I'm trying to displaying dictionary values in my template that i render from my views file. but its not displaying any value. In my html template show my just blank or not any error.

**views.py**

```
class BuyView(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'shop/buy.html'
     red_templateName = 'shop/receipt.html'

     def get(self, request, product_id):
          product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
          args = {'product':product}
          return render(request, self.template_name, args)

     def post(self, request, product_id):
          product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
          if request.POST['address'] and request.POST['quantity']:
               order = Order()
               order.or_proName = product.pro_name
               order.or_companyName = product.companyName
               order.or_quatity = request.POST['quantity']
               order.or_quatity = int( order.or_quatity)
               orderPrice = order.or_quatity*product.Sale_Price
               order.or_bill = 100 + orderPrice
               order.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
               product.Quantity -= order.or_quatity
               product.save()
               order = order.save()
               args = {'order':order}
               return render(request, self.red_templateName, args)

          else:
               return render(request, self.template_name, {'error':'Please Fill the address field'})
```

**template.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>

  <div class="container p-5" style="border:1px solid gray;">
    <small class="lead" >Your Order Receipt: </small>
        {{ order.or_id }}
        {{order.or_proName}}
        {{order.or_companyName}}
        {{order.or_quatity}}
        {{order.pub_date}}
        Deliever Chargers=100
        -----------------------
        Total = {{or_bill}}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: is `if request.POST['address'] and request.POST['quantity']` definitely true?

Comment: yes @RHSmith159. Everything is working fine but  `args = {'order':order} ` that is not work inn template

Answer (score 0):

Your template file name should match with following

```
red_templateName = 'shop/receipt.html'
```